# Do I need to Reduce the Width of a Power Trace for Thermal Relief When it's Passing Through a Pin on the Chip?

Tags: soldering, layout, manufacturing, reflow

I'm routing a PCB. Currently, all power traces are 20 mils. A QFP chip on the board requires multiple voltage rails to operate, I found the easiest solution is passing a power trace through a pin on the chip (the `1.8VI` net in the screenshot).

[image: PCB layout]

However, it means the trace is as wide as the pin itself. Will it acting as a heatsink and create a solderability / thermal balance problem in hand soldering or reduce the yield in reflow soldering? Should I reduce the trace width when it's passing a pin for thermal relief?

Comment: I thought thermal relief was only for hand soldering and it isn't an issue with reflow where ambient temp is high. Can't heat sink when everything is the same temperature. I've not had problems using traces as wide as the pad when getting boards assembled via oven.

Comment: If you have a connection to a large internal plane you end up with the suface traces hotter than the internal ones. Meaning those pins could not flow as well as the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traces do not connect to a large plane of copper nearby to the connection to the pin so it should not impact reliability. Think of it like if you double the thickness the trace should be twice as long to not be a larger heatsink

In your case the ground trace ends up going through a small trace to plane so the thermal relief is there. And while I cannot tell where the 1.8V trace is going. If its connection to plane is more than about 8mm away from the pin. For that thickness trace it should not effect things.